# Check if point lies within m-dimensional rectangle

Tags: c++, math, geometry, algebra

I'm trying to come up with a generalised algorithm for detecting whether a point lies within or on the boundary of a m-dimensional hyperrectangle defined using intervals.

For a 2D-case it is straight-forward and one can if point lies within a polygon using techniques such as ray-casting. However, how would one check for an m-dimensional hyperrectangle? Is there a way of say equation such a hyperrectangle and checking whether point lies within or on the boundary?

I'm trying to implement this in C++, are there any known libraries that may help?

Thanks! Help much appreciated!

Comment: Note that library recommendations are out of scope for stackoverflow and asking for them is likely to attract close votes.

Comment: See [softwarerecs.se] for libraries.

Comment: Thanks, Will do so :) I'm fairly new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the hyperrectangle (HR) stored as a combination of intervals (i.e. center coordinate + extent or beginning + end) and rotations, you can transform the query point into the coordinate system of the HR (through appropriate rotation, translation and scaling). Then you only have to do `2*m` bound checks.

Your suggested alternative of using a polyhedron is potentially a performance hog because an m-dimensional HR has `2^m` corner points.

*(This is of course assuming you are not restricting yourself to axis-aligned boxes, in which case the answer is of course trivial)*

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with straightforward approach?

```
if ((Point.x[0]>= Rect.min[0]) && (Point.x[0] <= Rect.max[0]) && 
 ...
   (Point.x[m-1]>= Rect.min[m-1]) && (Point.x[m-1] <= Rect.max[m-1]))
```

in loop by dimensions, of course

Comment: They did not specify the hyperrectangle to be axis aligned.

Comment: @Max Langhof  I thought that `defined using intervals` assumes axis aligned

Comment: Hm, I guess... That leaves me puzzled, as the question "how do I find out if a point is within a set of intervals" is beyond trivial.

Comment: Yes, corrected. Perhaps author will give more exact specification.

Comment: I have both scenarios for two separate problems, axis aligned and non-aligned axis...Thanks for your help